# Tizen 3.0 Gear S3 filesystem TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app

I have a web app that have worked good until Gear S3 got the tizen 3.0 update yesterday.

I have a problem with tizen.filesystem.resolve which I have no clue on how to solve. The code below is example code but generates the same issue.

Running this code would work in Tizen 2.3.2 (giving "success"):

```
try {
  tizen.filesystem.resolve('documents', function(dir){alert('success');},function(e) {alert('Error1 '+e);},"rw");
} catch (e) {
  alert("Error2: " +e);
}
```

But since the update it gives:

```
Error2: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
```

It goes to the catch. I have added the privileges (because it did work before the update). Anyone having any idea on whats wrong?

Also tried to create an entierly new project on 3.0, but it still gives the same error

Comment: I am facing same problem ...hope Samsung will fix this problem

Comment: And can you make sure that in the document folder, there is a file at least

Comment: Yes there are files in the folder. But do you think this is a bug? Or that something has changed but without updating the (awful) docs?

Comment: May be API updated/changed ...but the docs are not updated

Comment: https://bugs.tizen.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa Create a bug issue